# How to make egg-like shape with CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to make a shape similar to the one in this picture: [image]

Attempting to use border-radius to target the top-left and bottom-left corners of my div gets a close effect but am unable to get such a drastic curve. Is there an elegant solution to this? I've looked into clip-path a little but am not sure if that is the approach to take either.

Comment: Is svg not a suitable solution for you ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can SVG be used with google maps API?

Comment: What you mean by using with google api ? You want to integrate google map iframe into that shape ?

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FabienGreard Exactly. I already have the map set up and am just trying to contour it to that shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `border-radius` like this:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 120%;
  height: 150%;
  transform: rotate(-50deg) translate(45%, 15%);
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or use an SVG as a background:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64' fill='grey'><path d='M32 0 C12 28 10 18 38 64 L64 64 L64 0 Z' /></svg>") center/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to use a map below, you can try something like this:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64' fill='white'><path d='M32 0 C12 28 10 18 38 64 L0 64 L0 0 Z' /></svg>") center/100% 100% no-repeat,
  url(https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Any way to do it without the before pseudo element?

Comment: @VincentNguyen I added another way ;)

Comment: Great, thanks! This solves the original post but unfortunately it seems like I need to keep researching for an alternate solution because I was not specific enough in my OP. My real issue is the div will contain a google map, so I supposed I'd need to create SVG/pseudo elements that are the whitespace and cover the map with that otherwise my map will be all gray. Thank you.

Comment: @VincentNguyen Ok I see, still doable with my techniques .. I will edit my answer like you want ;)

Comment: I'm triyng to make the whitespace shape but am unsure how to create the circular part in the middle. I can make two top and bottom straight lines with ::before and ::after..

Comment: @VincentNguyen check the update, I invert the SVG

Comment: My div contains the map so I tried moving the SVG out to be its own separate element and making my div `clip-path` set to that svg. I am getting closer it has the right shape just too small

Comment: @VincentNguyen no need clip-path ... take the code I have wrote last and remove the background image and keep only the SVG then simply put that element above the map using position absolute

Comment: Seems to be almost working. I have set the height of the SVG to be 100% but it is going over the parent container into the next section below. Also because the svg must have a z-index to show above the map, I lose functionality of being able to click and drag on the map...maybe need to look for another solution not sure.

Comment: @VincentNguyen Ah if you want to be able to click/drag you can add `pointer-events: none;` to SVG also make the sure you add `position:relative` to parent element so the height doesn't overflow

Comment: Wow....it works can't believe it been working on this for 5 hours... wish I could give you more green checks. Will read into svg a little to learn how you came up with that path.

Comment: @VincentNguyen here is a link I use to create SVG shapes ;) http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M32%200%20C12%2028%2010%2018%2038%2064%20L0%2064%20L0%200%20Z

Comment: Great, thanks for that resource. Now to work on making it responsive as it shrinks on smaller screens :)